# Silex FW : Accessing custom services in Controller with scope resolution operator (::)

Tags: php, service, silex

Thanks in advance,

Here is my question, currently I'm working in Silex 2.0 framework. As per my requirement I have to create a Wrapper class for logging (to log the error messages) inside the services directory (let's say naming it as loggerService.php). So, I want to include/use the newly created service (loggerService.php) in all the controllers across the application. Currently we using **$app['loggerSer']** to create instance & call in controllers, but I don't want in that way. I need some thing like accessing the methods inside the "loggerService.php" using SCOPE RESOLUTION OPERATOR (::) or using $this-> . Please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

$app['loggerSer']->methodname(); ?